# Route matching with short distance routes in HERE maps

Tags: here-maps-rest

I am trying to find the distance between two points A and B with a shorter distance. The actual road distance is 700m. But HERE maps show 1.2km. On investigation, I found that HERE maps plots the points on the other side of the road and an additional U turn is needed and that's how the 1.2km.

The points were received from the HERE maps RME API and I am not sure on what basis its plotting the points on the other side of the road. Since the driver can travel 700m to reach the destination, I can not show this 1.2km on the screen.

Anyone faced this problem before ? Can someone with experience in HERE able to help me ?

Thanks in advance
T

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by changing the traffic mode to pedestrian instead of car. This is a workaround and will work as long as HERE maps resolve this issue.